# comparing distributions of pearson correlations with very small sample size

Tags: correlation, small-sample

I have a couple hundred 4-sample measurements for two different conditions. If I calculate Pearson correlation for these pairs of measurements to generate a distribution from all of my paired measurements, is comparison of this distribution to a shuffled distribution in which I scramble the pairings a meaningful analysis?

my concern is that the Pearson correlations of the original distribution are themselves not statistically significant in most cases due to the very small sample size.

Comment: Your concern is valid: with such small samples, you will only be able to detect very strong effects. Be careful using permutations in such cases: because of the number of possible permutations, the minimum possible p-value that you can compute may not be very small (I did not take the time to compute yet, but maybe you should). Also, do not forget to correct for multiple testing!

Comment: with a permutation test on 4 observations you wouldn't be able to do a 2 tailed test at the 5% level. There's only 24 permutations (assuming no ties), so the lowest achievable significance level is $\frac{1}{12}=8\frac13\%$. Even then you'd only reject for the most extreme associations available.

Comment: thanks for the responses - just to clarify, the shuffled distribution is generated by breaking the paired measurements. So if I had experiment 1 with 2 4-sample measurements, experiment 2 with 2 4-sample measurements, experiment 3 with 2 4-sample measurements, and so on, I am first measuring the correlation within the experiment between the 2 4-sample measurements to form a distribution, and then measuring the correlation when i scramble the pairs across experiments (so e.g. experiment 1, first 4-sample correlated against experiment 2, second 4-sample) to form a shuffled distribution.